# Using AngularJS, how can I create a checkbox that adds / removes all items in an array?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I am building a page where users can be selected. I have the code functioning properly for selecting / unselecting specific users, but I'm not sure how to tie it in with another function that selects / unselects all.

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Select All</label><br><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="addremoveall(all, user.ID)">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Continue" style="width:168.5px; margin-left:5.25px;" ng-click="buildprint()">
      <span>Continue</span>
    </button>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>User</th>
          .....
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="addremoveuser(checked, user.ID)"><td>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
          .....
      </tr>
    </table
</div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
    var array = [];

    $scope.addremoveuser = function (checked, id) {

            if (checked) {
                console.log("user selected", id);
                array.push(id)
                console.log("if test", array);
            }
            else {
                console.log("user unselected", id);
                var index = array.indexOf(id);
                array.splice(index);
                console.log("else test", array);
            }
    };

    $scope.addremoveall = function (all, id) {
            if (all) {
                console.log("all selected", id);
                array.push(id)
                console.log("if test", array);
            }
            else {
                console.log("all unselected", id);
                var index = array.indexOf(id);
                array.splice(index);
                console.log("else test", array);
            }
    };

});
```

How can I use `addremoveall()` to make it push all `id`s to the array when the checkbox is selected and make it remove all `id`s from the array when the checkbox is unselected? It also needs to account for items already pushed into the array if individual users are checked and then select all is checked. Could I just set the array to null and then add all `id's when checked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your DOM use ng-click insted of ng-change:

```
<label>Select All</label><br><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="addremoveall(all, user.ID)">
```

as

```
  <label>Select All</label><br><input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAllUser()" ng-model="checked">


  <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked" ng-change="optionToggled()"><td>
    <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
      .....
  </tr>
```

in your js file do change like this :

```
   $scope.addremoveuser = function (checked, id) {

            if (checked) {
                console.log("user selected", id);
                array.push(id)
                console.log("if test", array);
            }
            else {
                console.log("user unselected", id);
                var index = array.indexOf(id);
                array.splice(index);
                console.log("else test", array);
            }
    };

    $scope.addremoveall = function (all, id) {
            if (all) {
                console.log("all selected", id);
                array.push(id)
                console.log("if test", array);
            }
            else {
                console.log("all unselected", id);
                var index = array.indexOf(id);
                array.splice(index);
                console.log("else test", array);
            }
    };
```

to

```
  $scope.toggleAllUser = function() {
     var toggleStatus = !$scope.checked;
     angular.forEach($scope.users, function(itm){ itm.selected = toggleStatus; });

  }

  $scope.optionToggled = function(){
    $scope.isAllSelected = $scope.users.every(function(itm){ return itm.selected; })
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command in order to clear your array once you uncheck the select all check box.

array = [];

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything about question ?